# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification even after versions are same

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

This is all my gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.remindme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.+'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:+'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
}
```

but it still is giving me error on this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
```

I dont know whats wrong now any tips how to solve the issue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using SDK version of 28 and please build your SDK version from 28.

Steps:

1. Close the current project.
2. Click on `"Looking for updates"`.
3. Start update.

After the completion of your updates, go to setting and set your gradle offline and keep remember that your gradle should also be updated.

Thank you and I hope that will be helpful to you.